# How can I remove those extra chars after years

Tags: python

2011               2010             2009             2008(1)             2007(2)

How can I remove those extra chars after years

Comment: What you have tried already? Have you used `regexp`?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because no attempt has been made to demonstrate effort.

Comment: Please provide details when asking questions, e.g. which format are the list of years? Are they a list of strings or a single string? Do you need to split them?

Comment: Please show us that you've made an attempt and have a read of [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

If it is in string format use `str.strip()`

Example:

```
a = '2008(1)'
print a.strip('(1)') ---> '2008'
b = '2007(2)'
print b.strip('(2)') ---> '2007'
```

Comment: ``str.strip()`` strips leading and trailing ``[chars]``; So this will potentially have undesired side effects depending on the input.

Answer (score 0):

```
 # pass a string in t = '2011 2010 2009 2008(1) 2007(2)'

 import re
 t = ' '.join(re.sub('\(.*', '', i) for i in t.split())
```

*split is used for trailing or starting elements mostly not for middle elements.*